# how can I add when/if to buttons (viewBinding)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-button

I am trying to add when or if statement to my code. for example, once I press the first/second button it will change the colors of button,button2 to red. and if I just press the button3 it will become green. If there is also a way more easy method I am looking for it.

```
   `binding.button.isSelected
    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        binding.button.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.red)
    }
    binding.button2.isSelected
    binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
        binding.button2.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.red)
    }
    binding.button3.isSelected
    binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
        binding.button3.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.green)
    }`
```

**EDIT**

I did figure out thanks to @Tonnie, I had to change a few lines to work it as I intended. this is the code;

```
var isRedButtonsClicked = true
var isGreenButtonClicked = true


    fun colorButtonsRed() {
        binding.button.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red)
        binding.button2.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red)
    }

    fun colorButtonGreen() {
        binding.button3.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green)
    }

    binding.button.setOnClickListener {
        when (isRedButtonsClicked) {
            true -> colorButtonsRed()
        }

    }

    binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
        when (isRedButtonsClicked) {
            true -> colorButtonsRed()
        }

    }

    binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
        when (isGreenButtonClicked) {
            true -> colorButtonGreen()
        }

    }

    setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: That's about the simplest way to do it.  I'm not sure why you have isSelected calls in there, I don't think its doing anything unless you left out code.  The only problem in your code is that setBackgroundColor takes color constants, not drawables

Comment: @Talha, you are learning quite fast, nicely edited. Welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

@Gabe Sechan is right. You should use `setBackgroundColor()` with a Color Constant.

I am not sure what `isSelected` is intended to do but this code should work.

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            binding.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        }

        binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
           
            binding.button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        }

        binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
          
            binding.button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)

        }

        setContentView(binding.root)
        
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your effort but this is still not what I am looking for. in this case, just one button is working. I want to change the color of "button" and "button2" to red at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I get you, you need the Buttons to work simultaneously.

In this case try to build onto this code to suit your needs.

- First create a `var` which I name `isRedButtonsSelected` to monitor
  Button States.
- Add 2 functions to switch colors btw `Green/Red` and `Gray` (or any
  color you choose)
- Add 3 onClickListeners to change button Colors

The code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var isRedButtonsClicked = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            when (isRedButtonsClicked) {
                true -> colorButtons()
                false -> unColorButtons()
            }

        }

        binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
            when (isRedButtonsClicked) {
                true -> colorButtons()
                false -> unColorButtons()
            }

        }

        binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
            when (isRedButtonsClicked) {
                true -> colorButtons()
                false -> unColorButtons()
            }

        }

        setContentView(binding.root)

    }


    private fun colorButtons() {
        binding.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
        binding.button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
        binding.button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
        isRedButtonsClicked = false

    }

    private fun unColorButtons() {
        binding.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        binding.button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
        binding.button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
        isRedButtonsClicked = true

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you man, I did it and edited my post. I had to change a few lines, thanks to you I did figured it out!